# pass String from Java servlet to jsp to js

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I want to pass a String from a Servlet to a jsp page, where it has to be passed on to a init function that resides in an external .js. That's what I got so far:

**servlet**

```
request.setAttribute("jsonString", json.toString());
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("graph.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**jsp**

```
<body onload="init('<%= request.getParameter("jsonString") %>');">
```

**js**

```
function init(jsonString){

    var json = jsonString;
```

Unfortunately the only thing I receive in the init function is null. I made sure that json.toString() returns the correct value. So it must get lost between the forwarding and the init function. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an attribute, but retrieving a parameter, which is [not the same thing](http://www.coderanch.com/t/361868/Servlets/java/request-getParameter-request-getAttribute).
I think you should try [expression language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html)

```
<body onload="init('${jsonString}')">
```

You could also use `<%= request.getAttribute("jsonString") %>`, but to me it is less readable, whereas EL is more concise.

Comment: hmm sorry, I can't get it to run.. when I use the code I posted I can step through the code via the chrome debugger but as soon as I change that one line it won't stop at breakpoints anymore or print out my alert message. alert(jsonString) used to print out "null", now it does not even appear anymore, nor does an alert("test"), which is absolutely weird..

Comment: To see if your jsonString is passed to the JSP, you could print it directly in the HTML content. If it works, then you can see why it is not passed to your `init()` function. Also, if you are using jQuery, you can avoid `onload` events by replacing them with `$(function() { ... })`.

Comment: it's printed out correctly in the jsp file. seems like the init function in not called correctly since I never get to the breakpoints.. although I did not change anything else than getParameter to getAttribute

Comment: Just check the generated HTML output if it's syntactically valid. Perhaps you've newlines in your JSON string? Perhaps your JSON string should actually be represented as a concrete JSON object like so `<script>var json = ${jsonString}</script>` without singlequotes? Again, just look in the JSP-generated HTML output via rightclick and *View Source* in browser.

Comment: hm yeah, that does not look like the best way.. <body onload="init('{"id":"node0","name":"name0","children":[{"id":"node1","name":"name1"},{"id":"node2","name":"name2"},{"id":"node3","name":"name3"},{"id":"node4","name":"name4"}]}');">

Comment: Yeah, you have a problem with double quotes, the `init` is actually closed just after the first opening brace... As suggested by BalusC, you should create a JS variable directly using `<script>var json = '${jsonString}'</script>` (notice the single quotes surrouding the EL expression).

Comment: but how can I create a variable in the jsp file and then pass it to the onload="init()" function?

Comment: You don't need to pass it to the `onload`. You can put the previous snippet directly inside the `init()` function body :)

Answer (score 0):

See if you spot the difference,

> request.setAttribute("jsonString",json.toString());
>
> request.getParameter("jsonString")

It should be

> request.getAttribute("jsonString")

Comment: That makes sense.. but there is still one odd thing.. for debugging reasons I had the String pop up in the init function as alert(jsonstring) which printed out "null". Now there's no alert at all any more..

Comment: See the logs. You need to typecast it to String I guess.

Comment: how do I access these logs? there's noting in the tomcat's console

Answer (score 0):

Changing request.getParameter to request.getAttribute will get you the jsonstring, but if the string have new lines in it or any other special character like single quote ('), you'll likely get a javascript error. It will be hard for you to debug using an 'Alert ()' or printing as html on the page because of the javascript error. What I'll suggest is to use firebug plugin for firefox, and you would see the error on firebug console. Or you can do a view source of the page, and see how it's printing out the code.

Comment: yepp, got qoutes in the string.. and now I'm stuck and don't know how to get it to the init() function :/

Comment: Remove the quotes on the server side before you call setAttribute ().